# Error: The method '>=' was called on null

Tags: entity-framework, flutter, dart, methods, flutter-layout

I get some error in this code plz find out.
I have some error in running this method but I can't understand what this error want to say. This error crashes my app:

```
import 'dart:math';
class Brain{
Brain({this.height,this.weight});
    final  int height;
    final  int weight;
double _bmi;
String calculatebmi(){
  _bmi = weight / pow( height/100, 2);
  return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
}

String getresult(){
  if (_bmi >= 25){
    return 'OVERWEIGHT'; 
  }
  else if (_bmi > 18.5 ){
    return 'NORAML';
  }
  else{
    return 'UNDERWEIGHT';
  }
}



error=>
I/flutter (29335): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
I/flutter (29335): The method '>=' was called on null.
I/flutter (29335): Receiver: null
I/flutter (29335): Tried calling: >=(25)
I/flutter (29335):
I/flutter (29335): The relevant error-causing widget was:
```

Comment: There's only one occurrence of `>=` in your code. I suggest you use your own equivalent of your class to figure out what could be `null`. And please, next time look at all these recommendations you get while asking a question. You clearly ignored all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting _bmi to a value when you create the class, so unless you call your `calculatebmi()` function before calling `getResult()` it will throw that error since you can't do a comparison operation like `>=` on a null value in dart.

Try changing your initialization of _bmi to `double _bmi = 0;` or change your constructor to set it on creation with your calculation `weight / pow( height/100, 2)`.